# Po File Import Error in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, translate, po

I have this error, When i import .po file in drupal admin panel,

Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface

Error:   File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.

Error:   File to import not found.

Anybody know how to rectify this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this using Drush and Localization Update.

Install Localization Update

Configure a local path for po-files (admin/config/regional/language/update)

Configure automatic updates from remote servers or just local sources

Now you can put your own po-files in a local path (for example sites/all/translations). If you have translations for your own module then you name it according to this naming convention:

```
modulename-version.language.po
```

So a Swedish po-file for 'my_module', version 7.x-1.1 would be named:

```
my_module-7.x-1.1.sv.po
```

Now you have everything setup and you can start updating your sites translation with Drush:

```
drush l10n-update-refresh // Looks for new po-files
drush l10n-update // Updates translations
```